# How to disable auto-image-mode

Tags: image-mode, svg

Whenever I open an SVG file, emacs renders the image in the buffer.  I want it to let me edit the text (in nXML mode).

Of course I can exit image mode with C-c C-c, but I'd prefer that my *text* editor start me off with the text.

M-x auto-image-mode reports that it is toggling the Auto-Image-File mode to disabled, but the file still opens as an image (though smaller, curiously).

GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.24.30, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2022-01-24, modified by Debian

Answer (score 2):

Well this seems to drive a stake through its heart:

```
(auto-image-file-mode 0)
(setq auto-mode-alist (delete '(#1="\\.svgz?\\'" . image-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```